# 500 server error due to absence of async in controller? Need help removing an object from a list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to filter out all errors except one from a list of errors I send back to the front end. I realize this operation should be an async operation as my request is giving a 500 internal server error. I am new to C# and am having a hard time figuring out how to do so.

My code that gets invoked on the route request looks like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ProfileParams profileParameters)
    {
            // ...... //
            var user = await GenerateUser(Request.RequestContext);

            var userState = await _userStateFactory.CreateAsync(user);

            var stateTree = new BusinessProfileStateTreeModel
            {
                Global = await _globalStateFactory.CreateAsync(user),
                Header = await _headerStateFactory.CreateAsync(user, null),
                User = userState,
                Modals = _modalsStateFactory.Create(),
                Page = CreatePageState(),
                BusinessProfile = _businessProfileReviewsStateFactory.Create(viewModel, customerReviewModel),
                Analytics = await _analyticsStateFactory.CreateAsync(user, CreateDtmData(viewModel?.Categories?.PrimaryCategoryName, profileBbbInfo?.BbbName, viewModel), userState)
            };

            // trying to filter out errors here from the state tree alerts
            var errors = filterErrorsAsync(stateTree.BusinessProfile.Display.Alerts.AllAlerts);

            var metaData =
                GenerateProfileMetaData(customerReviewModel.NumFound, viewModel.ProfileUrl.ToUrlString(), viewModel);

            var serverSideModel =
                GenerateServerSideModel(
                    viewModel,
                    metaData,
                    profileBbbInfo,
                    stateTree.Analytics.DtmData,
                    user);

            return await ReduxViewAsync(stateTree.ToList(), serverSideModel);
        }
    }
```

The filterErrorsAsync method looks like:

```
   private List<BPAlert> filterErrorsAsync(List<BPAlert> allAlerts)
    {
        foreach (BPAlert alert in allAlerts)
        {
            if (alert.AlertTypeId == (int)BusinessReportCustomTextType.CustomerReviews)
            {
                allAlerts.Clear();
                allAlerts.Add(alert);
            }
        }
        return allAlerts;
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this correctly?

Comment: A 500 error is just a generic status code that the server sends if there's an error. You need to investigate and find out what the actual error was, by looking at logs or creating logs or recreating the error on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't loop a list and modify it at the same time. This is probably what is causing your 500 error.

It looks like you only want filter out certain errors from a list. If you want to keep your method as a loop you can do:

```
   private List<BPAlert> filterErrorsAsync(List<BPAlert> allAlerts)
    {
        List<BPAlert> temp = new List<BPAlert>(); //copy into new list
        foreach (BPAlert alert in allAlerts)
        {
            if (alert.AlertTypeId == (int)BusinessReportCustomTextType.CustomerReviews)
            {
                temp.Add(alert);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

If you want to be a little more modern you can also just use LINQ

```
   private List<BPAlert> filterErrorsAsync(List<BPAlert> allAlerts)
    {
        return allAlerts.Where(alert => alert.AlertTypeId == (int)BusinessReportCustomTextType.CustomerReviews).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to modify a list while enumerating it which won't work. Since you already know which kind of error you want to filter to, you can utilize LINQ's `Where` method to filter out the other errors, then use `Take` to get the first one.

```
private List<BPAlert> filterErrors(List<BPAlert> allAlerts) 
    => allAlerts.Where(alert => alert.AlertTypeID == (int)BusinessReportCustomTextType.CustomerReviews)
                .Take(1)
                .ToList();
```

There isn't anything asynchronous happening in this method, so no need to mark it async.